# concurrency::parallel_for iterates inconsistently each time

Tags: c++, loops, parallel.for

I am using parallel for in one of my application which contains a loop like below. My understanding is that the parallel_for loop will iterate through the entire range but not necessarily in sequential order, but it will iterate through the **entire range** none the less, yet I am getting inconsistent results for simple counting.

```
using namespace concurrency;
using namespace std;

#include <ppl.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
combinable<DWORD64> count[10];
int b, c;
for (c = 0; c < 10; c++)
{
    parallel_for(0, 52, [&](int a)
    {
        //printf("%d,", a);
        for (b = a + 1; b < 52; b++)
        {
            count[c].local()++;
        }
    });
    printf("\n%llu\n", count[c].combine(plus<DWORD64>()));
}
getchar();
}
```

considering `a` iterates from 0 to 51 and `b` iterates from `a + 1` to 51 the value of count[c] should be 1326 [(n*n+1)/2 where n = 51] every time? but its not. In fact every time I am getting a random count... but if I un-comment the first printf statement `printf("%d,", a);` magically the output is corrected?
How do i correct this? I suspect this has some synchronization issue which I am not resolving and the printf statement is somehow solving by introducing an arbitrary wait time.

What is the correct way to handle/use the parallel_for loops?

**SOLVED**
the second iterative loop variable `b` was scoped in main where as it should have been scoped locally in each thread, declaring the variable in the second loops solves the problem, But that Does not explayin why adding a printf in loop of `a` fixed the issue despite it `b` being  scoped incorrectly and experiencing race condition

Corrected code below

using namespace concurrency;
    using namespace std;

```
#include <ppl.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
combinable<DWORD64> count[10];
int c;
for (c = 0; c < 10; c++)
{
    parallel_for(0, 52, [&](int a)
    {
        //printf("%d,", a);
        for (int b = a + 1; b < 52; b++)
        {
            count[c].local()++;
        }
    });
    printf("\n%llu\n", count[c].combine(plus<DWORD64>()));
}
getchar();
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is a race condition, i.e., two or more threads try to update the count variable at the same time.

Comment: not true that is why the combineable variable is used which combines the local versions if each variable so count is updated per thread and then combines

Comment: Solved,, it is the race condition but not on the count variable, it is on the second loop variable (b) which was declared outside the loop, it should have been locally scoped